# Animating stroke-dashoffset can't close shape

Tags: animation, svg, path

I'm making a simple spinner using the dash-offset animation technique. you can see what i have [here](http://codepen.io/lee3/pen/xVYNWW). As you can see the polygon shape never closes. Is there any simple way to ensure the path completes the shape instead of leaving the miter corner at the top.

I could over shoot the path int he SVG so it overlaps to complete that final corner. Unfortunately you can see it overdraw in the animation which isn't ideal.

HTML

```
<div class="logo-container">
  <svg class="is2-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 243.514 195.632">
    <path class="gray-path" fill="none" stroke="#9A9A9A" stroke-width="16" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M121.71 64.26l106.08 61.04-106.08 61.033L15.724 125.3z"/>
    <path class="blue-path" fill="none" stroke="#00B3E9" stroke-width="16" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M121.71 9.225l106.08 61.04-106.08 61.032L15.724 70.265z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.logo-container {
  width: 400px;
  .is2-logo path {
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  .blue-path {
    animation: dash 2s linear forwards infinite;
  }
  .gray-path {
    animation: dash 2s linear forwards infinite .5s;
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0; 
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1000; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Create two other paths that are invisible except for a brief period when you want the paths to be drawn closed.

Comment: yea that was kind of my fallback plan, but it adds complexity and duplicates some effort. It'd also cause issues for if i want this placed on an image or a colored background for instance. I'm hoping there may be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

> completes the shape instead of leaving the miter corner at the top.

Actually it's leaving butt line-caps at the top.

Why don't you just make the blue path have round line-caps like the grey one has?

```css
.logo-container {
  width: 400px;
}
.logo-container .is2-logo path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
}
.logo-container .blue-path {
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards infinite;
}
.logo-container .gray-path {
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards infinite .5s;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: -1000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-container">
  <svg class="is2-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 243.514 195.632">
    <path class="gray-path" fill="none" stroke="#9A9A9A" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="16" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M121.71 64.26l106.08 61.04-106.08 61.033L15.724 125.3z"/>
    <path class="blue-path" fill="none" stroke="#00B3E9" stroke-width="16" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M121.71 9.225l106.08 61.04-106.08 61.032L15.724 70.265z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the clients logo is not rounded and I'm assuming they would reject this solution. It is easily the most elegant though. I'm investigating using marker start/ends now.

Comment: Which corner(s) of their logo are not rounded?  Just the top corner of the blue diamond?

Comment: none of the corners should be rounded, should look like stacked diamonds. Apologies if my pen had rounded corners which lead to this confusion, i'm poking around at it myself and probably saved by accident.

Comment: Extending the lines so they reach the top corner coordinate is the simplest solution.  What do you mean by "you can see them overdraw"?  What would you like it to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just extend the path by another leg, leaving the dash offset the same:

```html
  <svg class="is2-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 243.514 195.632">
    <path class="gray-path" fill="none" stroke="#9A9A9A" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M121.71 64.26l106.08 61.04-106.08 61.033L15.724 125.3 l106.08 -61.04 106.08 61.04" marker-end="url(#gray-start)"/>
    <path class="blue-path" fill="none" stroke="#00B3E9" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="16" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M121.71 9.225 l106.08 61.04 -106.08 61.032 L15.724 70.265 l106.08 -61.04 106.08 61.04"/>
  </svg>
```